# Текст не выравнивается по левой стороне

Tags: html, css, float, blocks

Не могу выровнять текст, чтобы был как на рисунке. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

```css
.infr-block {
  padding-top: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.infr-block-obj {
  width: 370px;
}

.infr-block-obj:nth-child(1) {
  padding-left: 130px;
}

.infr-block-obj h1 {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.infr-block-obj p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  width: 320px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.shadow {
  padding-top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infr-block">
  <div class="infr-block-obj">
    <h1>Социальные объекты</h1>
    <img class="shadow" src="img/shadow.png" alt="">
    <p>Волга: 350м, центральный пляж: 900м</p>
    <p>Авто парковка 5м.</p>
    <p>Игровая детская площадка 2м.</p>
    <p>4 продуктовых магазина в пределах 500м.</p>
    <p>Центр города: 4км.</p>
    <p>Почта 150007: 600м.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да все нормально, вот выравнивается...

Answer (score 1):

У вас как подметил @humster_spb `padding-left` стоит на первый элемент т.е. на `.infr-block-obj` больше информации о псевдоселекторе `:nth-child( <nth> [ of <selector># ]? )` [можно почитать на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```css
.infr-block {
  padding-top: 70px;
  float: left;
}

.infr-block-obj {
  width: 370px;
}


.infr-block-obj h1 {
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

.infr-block-obj p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  width: 320px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.shadow {
  padding-top: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="infr-block">
  <div class="infr-block-obj">
    <h1>Социальные объекты</h1>
    <img class="shadow" src="img/shadow.png" alt="">
    <p>Волга: 350м, центральный пляж: 900м</p>
    <p>Авто парковка 5м.</p>
    <p>Игровая детская площадка 2м.</p>
    <p>4 продуктовых магазина в пределах 500м.</p>
    <p>Центр города: 4км.</p>
    <p>Почта 150007: 600м.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно, чтобы к левому краю экрана всё прижалось? Уберите вот это:

```
.infr-block-obj:nth-child(1){
    padding-left: 130px;
}
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы текст в блоке прижимался к левому краю. Как сделать такое?